# Rails NoMethodError in Users#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently building a rails app which has the user log into a dashboard and fill out a form. I keep getting this error:

```
NoMethodError in Users#index
Showing C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/Sites/form-app/app/views/users/_dashboard_nav.html.erb where line #7 raised
undefined method `organization' for #<User:0x0000000c3e4de0>
```

UsersController.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def index
        @user = current_user
        # @organization = current_user.organization.all
    end

    def show
    end

end
```

_dashboard_nav.html.erb

```
...
 <% if @user.organization.exists? %>       <-- This is line 7
     <%= link_to "Profile", edit_user_organization_path(@user, @organization), class: "dashboard-nav__item" %>
 <% else %>
     <%= link_to "Profile", new_user_organization_path(@user, @organization), class: "dashboard-nav__item" %>
 <% end %>
...
```

organization.rb

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :organizations
  has_many :form_submissions
end
```

Comment: Now I am getting `undefined method 'organizations' for nil:NilClass` in the next page, same error same line everything.

Comment: The issue here is that you are missing an `s` in organizations `<% if @user.organizations.exists? %>` Rails conventions. Just as commentary... _Users controller is not controlling your user model cause it was generated by devise. The user model is controlled by devise controllers. You can override them but not my suggest. My suggest is to just use `current_user` in any place you are in the code. By the way, your `users_controller` will work with your custom views._

Comment: Before you use `current_user` in your controller you should ask if is `user_signed_in?` and then if `true` use `current_user`, the other way it will give you a `nil` class in `current_user` and break all your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just get rid of the instance variable `@user`. Also, you should use `organizations` instead of `organization`

Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   before_action :authenticate_user!

   def index
     # do nothing here
   end

   # other methods
end
```

View:

```
<% if current_user.organizations.exists? %>
  <%= link_to "Profile", edit_user_organization_path(current_user, @organization), class: "dashboard-nav__item" %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Profile", new_user_organization_path(current_user, @organization), class: "dashboard-nav__item" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If one user can have many organizations then the condition check should be

```
if @user.organizations.exists?
```

Comment: Now I am getting `undefined method 'organizations' for nil:NilClass` in the next page, same error same line everything.

Comment: @user must contain a user object, it's nil now, hence the error

Comment: I have looked this up and I see that it needs an object all the time. I'm pretty raw at programming, so I just don't register that. Is there an example you can give me of an object I can pass @user?

Comment: You have `organization` it should be **organizations**